# Best approach to interact with same data base table from more than one microservices

Tags: database, architecture, microservices, software-design

I have a situation, where I need to add/update/retrieve records from same database table from more than one microservices. I can think of below three approaches, please help me pick up the best suitable approach.

1. Having a dedicated Microservices say database-data-manager which will interact with data base and  & add/update/retrieve data and all the other microservices will call the end points of database-data-manager to add/update/retrieve data when required.
2. Having a maven library called database-data-manager and all the other microservices will use this library for the db interactions.
3. Having the same code(copy paste) in all the applications to take care of db interactions.

Approach - 1 seems expensive as we need to host a dedicated application for a basic functionality.
Approach - 2 would reduce boiler plate code but difficult to manage library version.
Approach - 3 would cause lot of boiler plate code and maintenance efforts to keep similar code in all the microservices.

Please suggest, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A strict definition of "microservice" would include the fact it's essentially self-contained... that would include any data storage it might need.  So you really have a collection of services talking to a common database.  Schematics aside...

Option 1 sounds like it's on the right track: you need to have something sitting between the microservices and database.  This could be a cache or a dedicated proxy service.  Let's say you have an old legacy system which is really fragile, controlling data in/out through a more capable service, acting as a proxy, is a well proven pattern.

Such a proxy might do a bulk read of the database, hold the data in memory to service high-volumes of reads, and handle updates.

Updating is non-trivial and there are various options:

1. The services cached data becomes the pseudo master - updates are applied to the cached data first, then go into a queue to apply to the underlying database.
2. The services data is used only for data-reads; updates are applied to the database first, and if the update is successful it is then applied to the cached data.

Option one is great for performance, on the assumption that the proxy service is really good at managing the data and satisfying service requests.  But, depending on how you implement, it might be vulnerable to outages, in which case you might lose any data that has made it into the cache but not into the pipeline that gets it into the database.

Option 2 is good for ensuring a solid master set of data, but there's the risk that consuming services might read cached data that is now out of date because it's just being updated in the database.

In terms of implementation, a queue of some sort to handle getting updates to the database might be something you want to consider, as it would give you a place to control how updates (and which updates) get to the database.

Comment: awesome thanks for the clear explanation.